# Hibernate Class Not Found Exception

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, maven, jpa

Всем привет! Изучаю понемногу java ee. Пытаюсь создать java ee проект через maven c поддержкой jpa/hibernate.
Алгоритм действий был такой:
1) Создал maven проект

2) Подключил зависимости в pom.xml:

3) Подключил TomEE Plume

4) Добавил поддержку JPA через add framework support

5) В persistence xml добавил провайдера
org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

В итоге при запуске получаю тонну Class Not Found Exception-ов:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
```

В pom.xml прописаны следующие зависимости:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SP1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>
введите сюда код
```

Содержание Persistence.xml:

```
    <persistence-unit name="JPATest">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entities.User</class>
    <properties>
        <!-- Configuring The Database Connection Details -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234" />

        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

В чем может быть проблема? Просьба сильно ногами не бить...

Comment: Кстати, если создать отдельный класс с методом main и запускать через него, а не как веб-приложение, то все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Сам столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой, не смотря на то, что были прописаны зависимости в pom.xml, нужные библиотеки не работали.

Откройте project structure, и там просмотрите artifact который вы загружаете на сервер. Скорее всего в нем не хватает каких-то нужных модулей проекта, и тогда там же вручную добавите их. Ну и в available elements возможно висят нужные вам библиотеки, прописанные в pom.xml. Там же можно будет добавить их в ./META-INF/lib

После у меня уже все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример Hibernate(он вам поможет):

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>home.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>home.hibernate.com</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?relaxAutoCommit=true&amp;amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;amp;useUnicode=true&amp;amp;characterEncoding=utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="home.hibernate.com.entity.Developer"/>
        <mapping class="home.hibernate.com.entity.Company"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.class:

```
public final class HibernateUtil {

    private HibernateUtil() {
    }

    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY =
            new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return SESSION_FACTORY;
    }

}
```

Factory.class:

```
public class Factory {

    private static Factory factory;
    private static CompanyDAO companyDAO;

    private Factory(Session session) {
        companyDAO = new CompanyDAOImpl(session);
    }

    public static final Factory getFactory(Session session) {
        if (nonNull(factory)) {
            return factory;
        }
        factory = new Factory(session);
        return factory;
    }

    public CompanyDAO getCompanyDAO() {
        return companyDAO;
    }
}
```

Company.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    public Company() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Company.class:

```
public interface CompanyDAO {

    void addCompany(Company company);

    void updateCompany(Company company);

    Company getCompanyById(int id);

    void deleteCompany(Company company);

    List<Company> getAllCompanies();

    void deleteCompanyByName(String name);

}
```

CompanyDAOImpl.class:

```
public class CompanyDAOImpl implements CompanyDAO {

    private Session session;

    public CompanyDAOImpl(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCompany(Company company) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(company);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCompany(Company company) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(company);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public Company getCompanyById(int id) {
        return session.load(Company.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCompany(Company company) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(company);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Company> getAllCompanies() {
        CriteriaQuery<Company> criteriaQuery = session.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Company.class);
        criteriaQuery.from(Company.class);
        return session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCompanyByName(String name) {
        session.beginTransaction();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaDelete<Company> criteriaDelete = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaDelete(Company.class);
        Root<Company> root = criteriaDelete.from(Company.class);
        criteriaDelete.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
        session.createQuery(criteriaDelete).executeUpdate();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Application.class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Factory factory = getFactory(session);

        CompanyDAO companyDAO = factory.getCompanyDAO();

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setName("company");

        companyDAO.addCompany(company);

        List<Company> companies = companyDAO.getAllCompanies();
        System.out.println(companies);

        session.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Но в сухом виде hibernate сейчас никто не использует. Лучше через Spring JPA. А в идеальном варианте Springboot + Spring Data JPA(тогда минимально настроек и приятно работать)